# iOS 4.3 support for AFNetworking - What can be the problems?

Tags: ios4, afnetworking

I have already an application developed with iOS 4.3+ support. I want to shift from [ASIHTTPRequest](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request) 
to AFNetworking but on the docs say that I should use the 0.10.x module rather than the current one. https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#requirements
The problem with using the current code (1.x) of AFNetworking is stated to be ( https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/545 ):

1. ARC introduction in 1.x
2. Use of [NSJSONSerialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. imp_implementationWithBlock() API difference

But iOS 4.3 supports ARClite, and going through the code of 1.x, I didn't come across any property using weak references that could cause problem. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/_index.html
iOS 4.3 supports [imp_implementationWithBlock()](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/03/17/ios-4-3-imp_implementationwithblock/)
There are only two references that use NSJSONSerialization, and I changed them to JSONKit calls ->

```
diff --git a/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m b/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m
index 62fc30a..3a60da5 100755
--- a/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m
+++ b/AFNetworking/AFHTTPClient.m
@@ -24,6 +24,7 @@

 #import "AFHTTPClient.h"
 #import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"
+#import "JSONKit.h"

 #import <Availability.h>

@@ -163,7 +164,7 @@ - (NSString *)URLEncodedStringValueWithEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)stringEncoding

 static NSString * AFJSONStringFromParameters(NSDictionary *parameters) {
     NSError *error = nil;
-    NSData *JSONData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error];;
+    NSData *JSONData = [parameters JSONDataWithOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:&error];

     if (!error) {
         return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:JSONData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
diff --git a/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m b/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m
index 607f247..c7367dc 100755
--- a/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m
+++ b/AFNetworking/AFJSONRequestOperation.m
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
 // THE SOFTWARE.

 #import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"
+#import "JSONKit.h"

 static dispatch_queue_t af_json_request_operation_processing_queue;
 static dispatch_queue_t json_request_operation_processing_queue() {
@@ -66,7 +67,7 @@ - (id)responseJSON {
         if ([self.responseData length] == 0) {
             self.responseJSON = nil;
         } else {
-            self.responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:0 error:&error];
+          self.responseJSON = [self.responseData objectFromJSONDataWithParseOptions:JKSerializeOptionNone error:&error];
         }

         self.JSONError = error;
```

Though this compiles beautifully, But i am still skeptical about doing it this way. Is this a correct way to go?

Comment: good question! Have you resolved this? I would like to know the answer as well.

Comment: @nanshi Yes, I have dropped support for iOS 4.3 There wasn't any answer from AFNetworking community, so I couldn't be sure of what I was doing was correct. Moreover, XCode stopped giving simulator for iPhone supporting the iOS 4.3 (which i inferred as an indication from Apple to move ahead). So, my app now supports only iOS 5+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are things you can change to get AFNetworking >= 1.0 to compile on iOS < 5, but this is not recommended, as other breaking changes may occur in subsequent releases.

But if happy with creating a fork that cannot incorporate mainline bug fixes and features, then there's nothing inherently wrong with your approach.